# vim not loading plugins with native packages

Tags: vim, package

I've got a plugin in `~/.vim/pack/messager/start/` called `messager`. After starting path, `:set runtimepath?` shows:

`runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/pack/messager/start/plugin,~/.vim/pack/messager/start/perl,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles                                                                                            ,/usr/share/vim/vim90,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after`

`:set packpath` shows:

```
packpath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim90,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after
```

However, `:scriptnames` shows:

```
:scriptnames
  1: /etc/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim90/colors/lists/default.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim90/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim90/scripts.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim90/autoload/dist/script.vim
  9: ~/.vimrc
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim90/ftplugin.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/gzip.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/logiPat.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/manpager.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/matchparen.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/spellfile.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/tohtml.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

So the plugin is not getting loaded automatically. vim shows I have +packages installed.

If I manually source the file, it loads fine.

My .vimrc is:

```
set nocompatible
set encoding=utf-8
let mapleader = ";"
filetype plugin on
syntax on
nnoremap <F5> :SendMessage CHUMP<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, read the documentation a little more closely:

```
Using a single plugin and loading it automatically

If you don't have a package but a single plugin, you need to create the extra directory level:
% mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/foo/start/foobar
% cd ~/.vim/pack/foo/start/foobar
% unzip /tmp/someplugin.zip

You would now have these files:
pack/foo/start/foobar/plugin/foo.vim
pack/foo/start/foobar/syntax/some.vim
From here it works like above.
```